# Navigation View XML doesn't let me interact with anything else

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm implementing a Navigation View on my `activityHome` for the first time. When i run the app and enter the home activity it function well. The problem is at the XML editor on the android studio, the `Nav View` is above all the other elements and doesn't let me click on them.

I haven't touch anything else but these yet.
Thanks.

[image: image of the problem]

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iv_menu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline46"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline139"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline135"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline45"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/menubuttonofthreelines_79781" />
...
```

and continues with the other elements.

Comment: Your layout has nothing wrong.. this is normal in the Android Studio design, it just shows you when the drawer is in the Open state, if you run the app, it will be in the closed state.. can you run the app and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout has nothing wrong..

The reason that Android Studio shows that the drawer layout in the Open state in the design view because you set `tools:openDrawer="start"` in the `DrawerLayout` .. if you want to see the main layout in the design mode (i.e. to make the drawer in the close state), then you need to remove this attribute.

This attribute won't affect the looking of your app when you launch it.

Documentation:

> You can insert sample data in your layout preview by using the tools: prefix instead of android: with any  attribute from the Android framework. This is useful when the attribute's value isn't populated until runtime but you want to see the effect beforehand, in the layout preview.

`XML` `tools` namespace is just used to show you some behavior on Android Studio, but not while you run the app. Please [check documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) for more info